# marking the .05 and the .95 interval for establishing the reference interval in laboratory

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval, density-plot

here is my Problem: I am working in a Lab and measured something in healthy and sick People. I would like to present the data in a histogram. here is what I got so far:

The structure of my data resembles this example data-set:
...

```
df_A <- data.frame( a = rep("A", length.out=2788), x =rnorm(seq(0, 15, length.out=2788),mean=2.443, sd=0.817))
df_B <- data.frame( a = rep("B", length.out=412), x =rnorm(seq(0, 15, length.out=412),mean=3.38, sd=1.68))
df_final<-rbind(df_A,df_B)
```

…
Here is the plot:
…

```
ggplot(df_final, aes(df_final$x, fill=df_final$a)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(density)), binwidth = 0.1,alpha = 0.4, position = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"), name="Cohorts",
                    labels=c("healthy", "sick")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.8))+
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2, linetype="dashed")+
  ylab("Percentage")+xlab("x")
```

…

Now I would like to highlight the tails of the blue distribution curve (5% and 95%) to represent the reference interval.
thank you Allan. After trying your Approach on my data I found diferences between the red marking of the geom_ribon and the geom_density.
Anny idea what to do with this? sorry for the messy posting. [image]

Answer (score 2):

I normally create a little supplementary density data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(x = density(df_A$x)$x, y = density(df_A$x)$y)
d$y[abs(cumsum(d$y * mean(diff(d$x))) - 0.5) < 0.45] <- 0
```

This can be added to your plot with `geom_area`:

```
ggplot(df_final, aes(x, fill = a)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(density)), binwidth = 0.1,
                 alpha = 0.4, position = "identity") +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2, linetype="dashed")+
  geom_area(aes(x = x, y = y), fill = "red", alpha = 0.6,
            data = d, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"), name="Cohorts",
                    labels=c("healthy", "sick")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800")) +
  labs(x = "x", y = "Percentage") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.8))
```

[image]

Just be careful that this is what you actually want: remember that plotting from 0.05 to 0.95 gives you a 90% confidence interval, *not* a 95% confidence interval. If you want a 95% confidence interval your density data frame should look like this:

```
d <- data.frame(x = density(df_A$x)$x, y = density(df_A$x)$y)
d$y[abs(cumsum(d$y * mean(diff(d$x))) - 0.5) < 0.475] <- 0
```